# Unit Testing - What to test?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing

So, I've done some reading on the advantages of Unit testing and creating test cases / suits in Xcode. I can see the advantages of this for avoiding things like regression and making sure new commits / builds don't break existing code.

What I am trying to figure out though - what do I test?

Do I create tests for every class I create?

At the moment, I am at the start of my project and I am busy creating a lot of model objects - these classes don't do that much - mainly to hold data that I parser in (from XML). Should I be creating test cases to make sure that each requirement of each object is met?

Taking the above example - if I wrote a single test suit like this for one of my model objects:

```
import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import "BBError.h"

@interface ErrorObjectTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation ErrorObjectTests
{
    BBError *error;
}
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];
    // Put setup code here; it will be run once, before the first test case.
    error = [[BBError alloc]init];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Put teardown code here; it will be run once, after the last test case.
    [super tearDown];

   error = nil; 
}


-(void)test_HasValidErrorCodeMessage
{
    error.code = @"Error Code";

    XCTAssertEqual(error.code, @"Code error",
                   @"BBError should have valid error code message");

}
```

Now if for some reason in my app - I set error.code to nil or don't assign an error code to it - will this test then fail?

I'm having trouble understating why it would fail then - because in the actual test method - I am assigning error.code to a string value. Should I leave this value out and then where I use this object, make sure error.code has a value in order for the test to pass?

P.S: Yes, I am aware that this particular test might not be the most accurate as I might not always getting an error in the first place - but this is just an example

Appreciate any input guys.

Comment: why the close frenzy? - Its a perfectly valid concrete question

Comment: @WarrenBurton better suited for programmers.stackexchange. It's offtopic here.

Comment: true . Looking again its not really a programming code question. OK question but wrong forum.

Answer (score 2):

When you're getting started with unit tests the most important thing is simply to **write** them. It's easy to get all-hyped at the begining and then gradually abandon the idea because of *deadlines*, *non-testable code*, *lack of coworkers support* and what not, especially if you were struck with *test everything* or *get 99% coverage* advices before. It's better to keep it pragmatic and focus on areas that might benefit you most, say:

- Test critical application features (majority of business logic)
- Test stuff that you expect might be problematic/has proved to be problematic in past
- Test stuff that is difficult/timeconsuming to test by other means
- Don't test data holder object (like [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_C%2B%2B_Object)); they rarely carry any logic and there's little value added in testing them

Walk your `error.code` test example through those points and try to decide for yourself.

#### Examples

> Test critical application features (majority of business logic)

One might argue that any code that is not critical to application workings/features should not be there in first place. This might sound appealing, but the truth is there's lot of code to ease developers' lives or help solve common problems which don't necessarily contribute to *feature development*. Do you test such code? Not always - if I refactored a method that combines 3 statements into one because they were commonly found together I might want to skip tests.

> Test stuff that you expect to be problematic/has proved to be problematic in past

This is fairly simple. We work on limited resources (namely time); testing everything is often too idyllic idea to implement in real world scenario. Many times you'll find yourself having to make a decission whether a piece of code will have tests written or not. When such time comes, favour complex code over simple code. Determining whether something is complex or not is of course judgement call and largely depends on your experience. But I suppose most people can make a decent guess about which of the following methods might be more problematic to deal with:

```
PrintLineToFile(string filePath, string line)
ComputeUserRisk(User user, RiskAssessment previousResult)
```

Also, if I can take a quick look at simple piece of code and know with decent degree of confidence that it works as I expect it to then I might skip unit testing it (but again, this is judgement call in *tight-deadlines/sparse-resources* times).

> Test stuff that is difficult/time-consuming to test by other means

Fact is, everything can be semi-autmatically tested by human tester, just by running your application and clicking buttons/executing commands. Note however that some pieces of code will be hard to *get to*. If in order to test `NumbersConverter` you need to upload file to server, load task creator, build new task and schedule it for running 30 seconds from now because that's the minimum time you need to hook up debugger... then you should consider having unit test for such `NumbersConverter` and don't manually run full-blown scenario each time `3.15` is returned instead of `3.16`.

#### Conclusion

Unfortunatelly, there is no *"do this and don't do that"-rule* - you'll have to grow your own approach depending on project type, domain, team, tools and probably many other factors. Some projects/domains require more rigid testing, others allow more slack. As with everything, always try to look at the context of what you're doing (unit testing) and try to predict what actions (tests) will benefit you the most at given times (aka *adapt*).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of unit testing is to assert that your class does what you expect it to when certain things happen. You are testing that your logic is correct. You are not testing the app as a whole.

A better name for your sample code test might be

`-(void)testErrorObjectHasValidCodeAtInitialisation`

because your test instantiates a `BBError` and then runs a test against its code property.

If at some point in the future you change your default `BBError` code to "Adventure Time" then the test will tell you that the change has been and should you have not intended to do this then you can fix the bug.

In short you test your logic in isolation from the app.

What to test. Test logic.

For a trivial example.

```
@implementation Foo

-(NSInteger)gimmeASeven
{
    return 7;
}

@end
```

The test might be.

```
-(void)testThatGimmeASevenReturnsSeven {

    Foo *testFoo = [[Foo alloc] init];

    NSInteger actualReturn = [testFoo gimmeASeven];

    NSInteger expectedReturn = 7;

    XCTAssertEqual(actualReturn, expectedReturn, @"method did not return 7 - why not?");


}
```

Its nothing to do with the App as a system. The test ensures that a given class/method always does what you expect it to do.

*Should* you be creating tests. Thats up to you and how you wish your product to evolve and be maintainable. I can't answer that.